# Is there anyway to retrieve the MCC of a store while making a transaction?

Tags: credit-card, banking, credit, payment

I'm trying to build an app that involves credit cards and I want to know if there's a way that I can get the merchant category code (MCC) of the store before I make a transaction using a credit card or before that transactions is fully processed.  I'm trying to use the MCC to determine what other credits cards a person could potentially use, so it has to be before that transaction actually completes.  Or alternatively, is there a way I can determine what store a person is making a transaction at before that transaction completes without using location?  Thanks!

Comment: A single physical location can have multiple MCCs depending on the type of the transaction

Comment: Yep. One big box here has a pharmacy, auto repair, home goods,  an audiologist, an optician, fast food, groceries, ... The question is what you're buying, not (just) where you bought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no kind of lookup service that will give you this information, and (as the comments say) there's the possibility of there being multiple MCC codes that apply to a particular location, depending on what their primary business is and how they divide up revenue centers.  Any given location in a large store is likely to only have one constant MCC (and not change on each transaction), but different registers in different departments likely will be different.

Pretty much the only way to know what the correct MCC code is is to be told it - either by the merchant's POS at the time of the transaction or by pre-configuration when the merchant is setting up your application.